# Notification Does Not Open Intent

Tags: java, android

When I click on the notification that pops up it doesn't open BaseApplication.class. What am I doing wrong here? I want the notification to open BaseApplication.class

```
public static void sendBasicNotification(int minor, int major, String task) {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(currentContext, BaseApplication.class);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("t", task);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("ma", major);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("mi", minor);

    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(currentContext, 0, new Intent[] { notifyIntent },
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int notificationID = 21;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(currentContext)
            .setContentText("You have started the task: " + task).setContentTitle("Task Alert")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager(currentContext);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
}

static NotificationManager getNotificationManager(Context context) {
    return (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: i have run your code and it works fine. please show your BaseApplication class.

Comment: public class BaseApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this, EstimoteManager.class));
    }
}

Comment: no setContentView() ? and have you put any Toast in service to show if the service is started ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line

```java
notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was sending the intent to the wrong class. Thanks all, fixed now. That code works just fine.

Comment: so comment on peoples post do not post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

> private void sendNotification(String msg) {
>
> ```
>   Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
>
>   mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
>             .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
> ```
>
> PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
>                   new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
>
> // MainActivity is the Notification Intent that open by intent
>
> ```
>   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
>             this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
>             .setContentTitle("Application name")
>             .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
>             .setContentText(msg);
>
>   mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
>   mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
>
>   Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
> ```
>
> }

hope it will work